# Why JNI can't find self-define static in enum?

Tags: java, c, static, enums, java-native-interface

i define a enum like below:

```
public enum EventType {
    UPDATE(0), ADD(1), REMOVE(2), RESPONSE(3);

    private Integer id;

    public Integer id() {
        return this.id();
    }

    /**
     * constructor method
     */
    EventType(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static EventType getInstance(Integer id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                return UPDATE;
            case 1:
                return ADD;
            case 2:
                return REMOVE;
            case 3:
                return RESPONSE;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a enum instance by callback getInstance method, the JNI code like below:

```
jclass eventType_cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/example/hellojni/EventType");
jmethodID midInstance = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,eventType_cls,"getInstance","(I)[Lcom/example/hellojni/EventType;");
```

it pass the compiler, but when run to the JNI GetStaticMethodID method, the platform throws a error like below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='getInstance' 
    signature='(I)Lcom/example/hellojni/EventType;' 
    in class Lcom/example/hellojni/EventType;
```

I don't know what's different enum with other class, do you have any idea?

Comment: `[Lcom/example/hellojni/EventType` appears to be an _Array_ of `com.example.hellojni.EventType`... or is that just a typo in your post?

Comment: Don't try to invent JNI method signatures. Use the output of 'javap -s'. It is never wrong.

Comment: Sorry, the '[' is a mistake in editing, because i try to get values() method after get getIntsnace() method.

Answer (score 2):

The signature that you use in JNI for the method is looking for a method that looks like this:

```
public static EventType[] getInstance(int id) {
}
```

So the return type of the signature is definitely wrong. It should not have the `[` there.

Now you have two possibilities either change the input type to `int` on the Java side **or** you change the type signature to `(Ljava/lang/Integer;)Lcom/example/hellojni/EventType;`.

Now you will realize that the second alternative is not very easy to handle since to access the value of the `Integer` you would have to use JNI methods and all the other fuzz.

You should also rethink why you would ever want to use the `Integer` wrapper instead of the primitive `int` in you Java code. There is simply no reason for it.

Rewrite your `enum` to something look like this:

```
public enum EventType {
    UPDATE(0), ADD(1), REMOVE(2), RESPONSE(3);

    private int id;

    public int id() {
        return this.id();
    }

    /**
     * constructor method
     */
    EventType(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static EventType getInstance(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                return UPDATE;
            case 1:
                return ADD;
            case 2:
                return REMOVE;
            case 3:
                return RESPONSE;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And change the JNI method lookup to this:

```
jmethodID midInstance = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,eventType_cls,"getInstance","(I)Lcom/example/hellojni/EventType;");
```